# regex in command line

Tags: regex, bash

I want to find the file with name like  ...(1-9)...

```
find . -regex '.*/.*\([1-9]\).*'
```

I first use this one, but it seems give me all file with 1-9 in their path.
And I try

```
find . -regex '.*/.*([1-9]).*'
```

and it works. But I don't know why. I remember in regex the parenthesis mean a expression? or you want to quote it later using sth like \1, \2? That's the reason I use backslash to escape it.

Any one can help me out? Thx

sorry am I making confusing here? I want Sth like book(1).pdf instead of book1.pdf
.*[1-9].* is not workable?

Comment: Why not: `find . -regex '.*[1-9].*'` (you actually do not need `-regex` for this)

Comment: @anubhava he wants `[1-9]` to be present in the file name.

Comment: @anubhava a poossible answer is book(1).pdf, book1.pdf is not what I'm looking for

Comment: ok check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need `find` for this. Just use glob expression to match `([1-9)` pattern:

```
printf "%s\n" *\([1-9]\)*
```

Note that this will list all the files and sub-directories in current path with name `([1-9])`.

If you only want to list files with this pattern then use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*([1-9])*' -type f
```

Comment: Thx u for providing an useful option as well:)

Comment: `find . -regex '.*/.*([1-9]).*'` works because `(` and `)` act as literal parentheses. When you use `'.*/.*\([1-9]\).*'` then  `(` and `)` act as regex grouping hence any file/dir with `[1-9]` is matched. Having said that what I have shown in my answer is better option.

Comment: Seems I take the opposite as right one for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but I check on the internet but parenthesis have special meaning? So we should escape to use literal (?

Comment: No the default regex engine of `find` is `emacs`. That treats unescaped parentheses as literals.

Comment: Oh that's where the rub is. Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use negated char class.

```
find . -regex '.*/[^/]*\([1-9]\)[^/]*$'
```

Comment: Yes, probably the same output as I use the first regex. BTW, I restate sth unclear in my question~